# Singular Value decomposition positive components

Tags: matlab, svd

I am using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) applied to Singular Spectrum Analysis (SSA) of a timeseries.

```
% original time series
x1= rand(1,10000);
N = length(x1);

% windows for trajectory matrix
L = 600;
K=N-L+1; 

% trajectory matrix/matrix of lagged vectors
X = buffer(x1, L, L-1, 'nodelay'); 

% Covariance matrix
A = X * X' / K;

% SVD
[U, S_temp, ~] = svd(A);


% The eigenvalues of A are the squared eigenvalues of X
S = sqrt(S_temp);
d = diag(S);
% Principal components
V = X' * U;
for i = 1 : L
    V(:, i) = V(:, i) / d(i);             
end
```

**EDIT 1:**

If I try to reconstruct the original matrix X adding the i-matrices given by d(i)*U(:,i)*V(:,i)' I get exactly the original matrix.

```
X_rec = zeros(size(X));
for index_col = 1 : L
    disp(index_col)
    X_i = d(index_col)*U(:,index_col)*V(:,index_col)';
    X_rec=X_rec+X_i;
end
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to have the singular components V always positive with the compromise of having an error in the recostructed matrix.
In this case the reconstructed matrix would be just an approximation of the original.

X is always > 0 in my case (and also the Covariance matrix A)

Comment: What exactly bothers you? That `S` sometimes has zero values or that `U` is partly negative?

Comment: The singular values are in $S$, and they are always non-negative.

Comment: That some values of V are negative...I edited my question to be more specific

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVD (singular value decomposition) and SSA (singular spectrum analysis) adding constrains on components](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143385/svd-singular-value-decomposition-and-ssa-singular-spectrum-analysis-adding-c)

Comment: According to [Frobenius-Perron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) theorem, if `X` is positive the fisrt vector in `V` and in `U` are complitely positive too. Or, more strictly, either completely positive or completely negative - depending on your svd function realization.

Comment: @ttnphns Yes, this is right! indeed I get the first singular vector always positive. How can I get all the singular vectors positive? I would like that SVD (or something else) decomposes my original matrix in additive matrices of positive values..

Comment: I'm not an expert in specifically math side of it, but I think it is impossible to get what you want with svd: some values except in the 1st vector will always be negative. Perhaps you want some other orthogonalization procedure, not svd?

Comment: @ttnphns this is fine with me, but I couldn't find any so I thought that modifying SVD with the compromise of losing the exact recontruction of the original matrix.

Comment: @ttnphns I edited the question to explain this point..

Comment: @gung: I don't really know which one to close. The OP has posted this question at least five times on SO and stats.SE, I just wanted to link the question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add a non-negativity constraint to the right-singular vectors, $V$.

However, you must specify how "far" from 0 the elements can be to be an acceptable solution.

Let your optimisation problem be
$$
    \text{maximise}\; \frac12\|Xv\|_2^2,
$$
$$
    \text{subject to}\; \|v\|_2\leq1 \;\text{and}\; v_i > \varepsilon, \forall i.
$$
This is a convex optimisation problem with convex constraints. The projection onto the non-negative orthant is
$$
    \rho_+(x) = \begin{cases}
                  x_i & \text{if}\; x_i > \varepsilon, \forall i\\
                  \varepsilon   & \text{otherwise}.
              \end{cases}
$$
and the projection onto the $\ell_2$ norm ball is
$$
    \rho_{\ell_2}(x) = \begin{cases}
                           x & \textit{if}\; \|x\|_2<1 \\
                           \frac{x}{\|x\|_2} & \text{otherwise}.
                       \end{cases}
$$

I am not 100 % sure, but I *think* that the projection onto the intersection of these constraints is:
$$
    \rho(x) = \rho_{\ell_2}(\rho_+(x))
$$

A trivial algorithm would then be:
$$
    v^{k+1} = \rho(v^k - t\nabla \frac12\|Xv^k\|_2^2) = \rho(v^k - tX^TXv^k),
$$
where $t$ is a step size. This method is called projected gradient descent.

This solution will be the closest approximation (in a squared $\ell_2$ sense) to the SVD, but with a non-negativity constraint on the right-singular vectors.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I am not familiar with optimization problems... could you explain a bit more? is v the same of V?

Comment: @TommyL: [Wiki states:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values.2C_singular_vectors.2C_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD) *Non-degenerate singular values always have unique left- and right-singular vectors, up to multiplication by a unit-phase factor*. So you won't get lucky most of the time.

Comment: @gabboshow Yes, $v$ would be a right-singular vector. In order to obtain more than one you would have to either add an orthogonality constraint, or deflate the component from $X$. The simplest is deflation (but it has its own problems). After the first component, let $X := X - Xvv^T$, and run the algorithm again to find the second component.

Comment: @TommyL What you are suggesting is to iteratively run SVD? run the first time, reconstruct X taking out and saving the first component and running again and again SVD?

Comment: @knedlsepp I'm not sure what you mean by being lucky. This would not be the singular vectors, but would be the ones maximising the variance, under the constraint of non-negativeness.

Comment: @gabboshow Not really. I suggest that you extract one singular vector at the time, and constraint them all to non-negativeness.

Comment: The OP asks for a way to enforce non-negativity of every component of the singular vectors, while still maintaining a singular value decomposition. Changing the matrix `V` of a SVD is only possible for degenerate singular values and not even then guaranteed to be able to yield all non-negative values.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. What I would like to have is a decomposition of the initial matrix in additive matrices. I can do this by using SVD, but I get negative singular vectors (that I do not want). A good point of using SVD is of course that I can organize the singular vectors according to the values of the eigenvalues and then group them together, but this is not my priority...

Comment: @knedlsepp Of course, what I propose is not the SVD, but it is the closest non-negative approximation to the SVD. What I propose is a decomposition that maximises the variance of the data matrix $X$ (just like SVD does) but which is constrainted to non-negative right-singular vectors.

Comment: @TommyL: I see. Reading your answer it doesn't come across really well, that the thing you are generating is not a SVD anymore. (However the OP doesn't really know what he wants anyway and has posted this question for the 5th time at least.)

Comment: @knedlsepp Ok, I added a clarification to my answer. I thought it should be obvious that this is not really the SVD (just as ridge regression is not MLR). OP cannot use the SVD, as he points out himself, and so his only option is to constrain the solution like this.

Comment: @TommyL thanks for your answer! Would you be so kind to provide with the matlab implementation of your answer? I am struggling with that..